# This is a picture on my LG TV screensaver. I would like to know where this is?

Tags: identify-this

[image]

The screensaver on my TV shows this place; I would love to find where it is located!

Comment: You can view these pictures without using screen saver by pressing the "home" key, scrolling right to "photo & video", then selecting the "sample ..." circle on the right.

Answer (score 85):

**Hallstätter See** (a lake in Austria)

Source:  [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hallst%C3%A4tter%20See&source=lnms&tbm=isch)

> Hallstätter See or Lake Hallstatt is a lake in the Salzkammergut, Austria, located at 47°34′43″N 13°39′38″E. It is named after Hallstatt, a small market town in Austria, famous for its salt mining since prehistoric times and the starting point of the world's oldest and still working industrial pipeline – for brine to Bad Ischl (since 1596) and further to Ebensee.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallst%C3%A4tter_See)

---

**Pro Tip:**

I often see questions like this, and, while I do believe they are on-topic and related to travel, they are extremely easy to self answer.

1. Remove any extra areas from your picture (for example, the areas outside your TV screen in this case)
2. Go to Google Image Search and click on the Camera button.
3. Upload the picture, Search and let Google do its magic.

Or if you have Google Chrome, right click on the image and click **Search Google for image**. This was kindly suggested by [Andrew T](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124256/this-is-a-picture-on-my-lg-tv-screensaver-i-would-like-to-know-where-this-is/124257?noredirect=1#comment306827_124257) below this answer.

If Google fails to find the answer then it's a good challenge.

Comment: Photo from Google Maps shows the spot where this was taken (in very different weather): https://www.google.com/maps/@47.56471,13.6499324,3a,75y,169.5h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipPHvg1pw_qQMvVBRTt7JDEnpZWeVrOgHqAHY3bE!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPHvg1pw_qQMvVBRTt7JDEnpZWeVrOgHqAHY3bE%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-2.9338646-ya32.499992-ro-0-fo100!7i10240!8i5120?hl=en

Comment: Or if using Chrome, just right-click the image and select "Search Google for Image" (even works for OP's original image)

Comment: @PaulPalmpje That's so depressing!

Comment: Upvoted, not for the answer, but for describing the method.